# INSERT repeating values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to find a simple way to insert some repeating values in two columns in my table, something similar to the `rep` function in `R`-

for instance, I need to insert two values (chocolate and vanilla, 4 times each) and I need to insert 4 types of values that repeat twice such as --

```
flavor_type schedule_type
chocolate   weekly
chocolate   monthly
chocolate   quarterly
chocolate   yearly
vanilla     weekly
vanilla     monthly
vanilla     quarterly
vanilla     yearly
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cross join`:

```
select *
from (values('chocolate'), ('vanilla')) flavor(flavor_type)
cross join (values('weekly'), ('monthly'), ('quarterly'), ('yearly')) schedule(schedule_type)
```

Output:

```
flavor_type schedule_type
----------- -------------
chocolate   weekly
chocolate   monthly
chocolate   quarterly
chocolate   yearly
vanilla     weekly
vanilla     monthly
vanilla     quarterly
vanilla     yearly
```

Comment: Hm, this seems to give me a table with a total of 5 columns and 2 rows: 

* one column for flavor type with no repetition - just two distinct values
* four columns for each respective schedule type, repeated for flavor

Comment: @S31, this query produces a resultset with two columns and eight rows, pls see answer.