# Avoid repeating predefined value in SQL insert into

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, lateral-join

I am looking to insert a couple of values associated to a pair of ids without hardcoding those ids in the query.
More concretely, I have this table `foo`:

```sql
create table if not exists foo(id int, val text);
```

and I can insert my values by doing:

```
insert into foo
values
  (10, 'qwe_1'),
  (10, 'qwe_2'),
  (10, 'qwe_3'),
  (20, 'qwe_2'),
  (20, 'asd_3'),
  (20, 'asd_4');
```

but I do not want to repeat those `10` and `20`.

I asked a similar question a while ago ([SQL - Using WITH to declare variable on INSERT INTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60761298/sql-using-with-to-declare-variable-on-insert-into)) but it does not solve my problem.
Neither can I understand how to use a join or similar as suggested in [INSERT repeating values in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926698/insert-repeating-values-in-sql), since the list of values I want to add per id is arbitrary.

---

While not strictly needed I would like to use a `with` statement to first declare my ids:

```
with c (first_id, second_id) as (values (10, 20))
select * from c;
```

but I don't understand how to combine that with the `insert into` statement. I have this **non working** query but which illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:

```
with c (first_id, second_id) as (values (10, 20))
insert into foo
values
  (c.first_id, 'qwe_1'),
  (c.first_id, 'qwe_2'),
  (c.first_id, 'qwe_3'),
  (c.second_id, 'qwe_2'),
  (c.second_id, 'asd_3'),
  (c.second_id, 'asd_4')
from c;
```

---

My understanding is that the `values (...), ...` statement returns a table so maybe what I am lacking is a way of combining this table with the `c` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a lateral join:

```
insert into foo (id, val)
    select v.id, v.val
    from (values (10, 20)) c(first_id, second_id) cross join lateral
         (values (c.first_id, 'qwe_1'),
                 (c.first_id, 'qwe_2'),
                 (c.first_id, 'qwe_3'),
                 (c.second_id, 'qwe_2'),
                 (c.second_id, 'asd_3'),
                 (c.second_id, 'asd_4')
         ) v(id, val);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're able to use a block structure, I would use that route.

```
do $$
DEFINE
    v_first_id  NUMBER := 10;
    v_second_id NUMBER := 20;
BEGIN
    ... Your Insert Statement ...
END; $$
```

Comment: This looks a bit simpler, I managed to get it working with the following query:
```
do $$
DECLARE
    v_first_id  integer := 10;
    v_second_id integer := 20;
BEGIN
  insert into foo
  values
    (v_first_id, 'qwe_1'),
    (v_first_id, 'qwe_2'),
    (v_first_id, 'qwe_3'),
    (v_second_id, 'qwe_2'),
    (v_second_id, 'asd_3'),
    (v_second_id, 'asd_4');
END; $$ language plpgsql
```